# Drop down does not show the option in correct format selected in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
<datalist id="stoplist">
Array
(   

    [0] => Array
        (
            [stops] => katraj dairy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [stops] => bharati vidyapith
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [stops] => balaji nagar
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [stops] => k k market 
        )


)
</datalist>
```

This is my view

```
foreach ($data1 as $row) {
  echo "<option value=".$row['stops'].">".$row['stops']."</option>";
}
```

When I select katraj dairy I get only katraj as a value.

I am getting correct value from database as I print above. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your controller you need to pass data from your controller before you can access it from your view.

```
 &this->load->view("viewname.php",$data)
```

Where $data is the array you get from your database

format for select option

```
     <select>
     <option value="">name</option>
      </select>
```

Modified code:

```
    echo "<select>";
    foreach ($data1 as $row) {
    echo "<option value=".$row['stops'].">".$row['stops']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```